# How to have all tinymce editors as standard except selected

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE as a text editor.
In the header I have defined that all `<textarea>` selectors must be TinyMCE.
I have set the height as 300px as default, but now I need to add a text area which is much smaller.

I have tried the code below to make try and have it use the default settings and only override the selected textarea but it is not working. Not throwing any errors. Just seems to ignore the code.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="footer_editor" name="template_footer" id="template_footer" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $template_footer; ?></textarea>
```

**Code**

```
tinymce.init({
                selector:'textarea',
                relative_urls : false,
                remove_script_host : false,
                document_base_url : "<?php  print(get_system_url()); ?>",
                height : "360",
                fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
                font_formats: "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;"+
                "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
                "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;"+
                "Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;"+
                "Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;"+
                "Courier New=courier new,courier;"+
                "Georgia=georgia,palatino;"+
                "Helvetica=helvetica;"+
                "Impact=impact,chicago;"+
                "Symbol=symbol;"+
                "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
                "Terminal=terminal,monaco;"+
                "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;"+
                "Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;"+
                "Verdana=verdana,geneva;"+
                "Webdings=webdings;"+
                "Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",
                plugins: "image,advlist, table, autolink, charmap, code, colorpicker, contextmenu,link, lists, paste, preview, searchreplace,  spellchecker, textcolor, wordcount,emoticons"<?php //,lioniteimages"*/?>,
                /*image_list: [ 
                {title: 'My image 1', value: 'http://www.tinymce.com/my1.gif'}, 
                {title: 'My image 2', value: 'http://www.moxiecode.com/my2.gif'} 
            ],*/
                toolbar: "fontselect | fontsizeselect | forecolor | backcolor | bold | italic | underline | alignleft | aligncenter | alignright | alignjustify | bullist | numlist | outdent | indent | link | <?php //lioniteimages |?> image | print | media | code",
                tools: "inserttable",
                contextmenu: "link image inserttable | cell row column deletetable"
         });

tinymce.init({
                    mode : "specific_textareas",
                    editor_selector : "footer_editor",
                    height : "100"                
             });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple TinyMCE Fiddle that shows two textarea tags that are used to invoke two TinyMCE instances with different heights:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gqfaab

Your first init uses the selector of `textarea` so I suspect that you already have TinyMCE initialized on the textarea for `footerarea` before your second init is called and since the textarea is already setup for TinyMCE the second init call likely does nothing.  If you change the selector of the first init in my fiddle from `textarea#area1` to `textarea` you will see that the second init no longer impacts the other text area.

My recommendation would be to use targeted selectors (e.g. reference the ID of each textarea `textarea#area1` or use classes to group them together `textarea.regular`) when you want to use different inits for different editors on the same page.

Comment: Thank you. Seemed to resolve the issue fairly easily.

Answer (score 2):

Use an initialization object

```
var init_obj = {
    selector:'textarea:not(.footer_editor)',
    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false,
    document_base_url : "<?php  print(get_system_url()); ?>",
    height : "360",
    fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
    font_formats: "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;"+
    "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
    "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;"+
    "Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;"+
    "Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;"+
    "Courier New=courier new,courier;"+
    "Georgia=georgia,palatino;"+
    "Helvetica=helvetica;"+
    "Impact=impact,chicago;"+
    "Symbol=symbol;"+
    "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
    "Terminal=terminal,monaco;"+
    "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;"+
    "Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;"+
    "Verdana=verdana,geneva;"+
    "Webdings=webdings;"+
    "Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",
    plugins: "image,advlist, table, autolink, charmap, code, colorpicker, contextmenu,link, lists, paste, preview, searchreplace,  spellchecker, textcolor, wordcount,emoticons"<?php //,lioniteimages"*/?>,
    toolbar: "fontselect | fontsizeselect | forecolor | backcolor | bold | italic | underline | alignleft | aligncenter | alignright | alignjustify | bullist | numlist | outdent | indent | link | <?php //lioniteimages |?> image | print | media | code",
    tools: "inserttable",
    contextmenu: "link image inserttable | cell row column deletetable"
}

tinymce.init(init_obj);

init_obj.selector = 'textarea.footer_editor';
init_obj.height = 300;

tinymce.init(init_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

editor_selector : ".footer_editor"

If you want to use class as selector, don't forget using . before class name

Comment: It does not work. The editor still uses the first size of `360` in the footer editor aswell

Comment: try using a new initialization for the exception :

selector:'textarea#template_footer',